# How to make only part of the layout scrollable with ScrollView and Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, scrollable

I have a layout.xml that is divided into 2 parts, one of which includes fields that are filled vertically, and the other part (initial), includes 3 cardviews that will be used to be filled with an imageView (later), however, when trying to let only the cardviews scroll horizontally, nothing happens, the only thing that happens is that the entire layout is scrolling vertically, but nothing of the cardviews scrolling horizontally.

Code of .xml archive:

```java
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Adicione até 3 fotos do seu produto"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bevan"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/anuncioImg1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="6dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"/>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/anuncioImg2"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="6dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"/>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/anuncioImg3"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="6dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"/>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/anuncioImg4"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="6dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+"/>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/anuncioImg5"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_margin="6dp">
                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="+"/>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="Título do Anúncio:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title" />
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Ex: Gado Nelore 300Kg"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_text_fields_24dp"
        app:startIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        app:counterTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tituloAnuncio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"
            android:maxLength="30" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="Descrição:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title" />
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Ex: Gado 20 meses de vida, 10 arrobas..."
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_short_text_24dp"
            app:startIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="240"
            app:counterTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editDescAnuncio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="240"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="Preço:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title" />
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Ex: 1650"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_monetization_on"
            app:startIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="6"
            app:counterTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:prefixText="R$"
            app:prefixTextColor="@android:color/black">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editPrecoAnuncio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                android:maxLength="6" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="Telefone do anunciante:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title" />
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Ex: 64999999999, apenas números"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/fui_ic_phone_white_24dp"
            app:startIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="11"
            app:counterTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/numeroAnuncio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="11" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_addAnuncio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:fontFamily="@font/baumans"
            android:text="@string/avisoVenda"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how you can do it... Forget about FrameLayout, use the Linear as the main Layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/avli_horse"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bar"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/kitchen"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/avli_logo"/>

        </GridLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/avli_horse" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bar" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/kitchen" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/avli_logo" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, i did not know the Horizontal Scrollview, i'll test and choice your answer as great, after.

Comment: in your .xml who is the layout that is above all (top) and that covers the entire code? the one that contains the attributes
     xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: I got with "horizontal scroll view", VERY THANKS

Comment: @lukecross "in your .xml who is the layout that is above all (top)" that is the main LinearLayout. I didn't add it here, but that's why I mentioned it...

Answer (score 1):

You have to add another layout where you will place your scrollView... But the structure of your XML is not good. Firstly you have to have 2 LinearLayouts, first one for the horizontal ScrolView with your CardViews, and the second for the vertical ScrolView with the rest of your XML... If you need more help, let me know!

Comment: so what should my layout start with .xml? a relative?

Comment: Whenever I work with ScrolView I use just FrameLayout

Comment: So, i must be to separate the horizontal and vertical scrollable to 2 frame layouts?

Comment: @lukecross, have a look at what I posted just now... So as the main Layout use LinearLayout, and then just try to follow the code I posted. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of ScrollView in another ScrollView is unpredictable, you should try NestedScrollingParent2 and NestedScrollingChild2.

Comment: This Examples are external libraries?